# modx revolution babel - pages are unavailable when I'm not logged on

Tags: modx, babeljs

I've installed this package as it is mentioned in instruction and I get this strange error ...

Answer (score 0):

OK I have found the solution to this irritating issue. The installation guide is wrong!!! In each context permission settings change "Access Policy" for  (anonymous) to "Context" or (no policy). I hope It can help someone and prevent from wasting time..